# Knockout mappingOptions for ko.mapping.toJSON()-method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

### Problem

I'm trying to send a modified viewModel back to my server. Unfortunately I have to create my viewModel using *ko.mapping.fromJSON()* and some mappingOptions, which is working fine. Now I need an **easy** way to convert the created viewModel back to the original scheme.

### Desired result

I want to convert this:

```
var myModel = {
    simpleProp: "test",
    complexProp: {
        simpleProp2: "test2",
        simpleProp3: "test3"
    }
};
```

into that (JS):

```
var myModel = {
    simpleProp: "test",
    modifiedToSimpleProWithNewName: "test2"
};
```

giving me this JSON:

```
{"simpleProp":"test","modifiedToSimplePropWithNewName": "test2"}
```

### Attempts

I was thinking that, since *ko.mapping.toJSON* has a mapping parameter, it is as easy as creating another mapping for this method. But it seems like ko.mapping is actually ignoring my custom property creation:

```
var mappingOptions = {

    // ignored
    'simpleProp': {
        create: function (thing) {
            return "Changed simpleProps value";
        }
    },

    // working
    ignore: ["simpleProp3"]

};
```

### Further Information

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/okzczhuz/4/) for you.

Please notice: I've simplified the example removing the model generation using fromJSON:

```
// created and modified by ko.mapping.fromJSON - with custom mapping!
var myModel = {
    simpleProp: "test",
    complexProp: {
        simpleProp2: "test2",
        simpleProp3: "test3"
    }
};
```

The result will be:

```
{"simpleProp":"test","complexProp":{"simpleProp2":"test2"}}
```

And as you can see, the *ignore* option will be applied, while the *'simpleProb'/create* won't.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I know that this mapping will not achive the desired result. It was just a "will *'simpleProp'* be modified?"-test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping plugins toJSON method will, like the JSON.stringify function, check and use the return value of any toJSON method that might exist on the object before stringifying it to JSON.

Therefore you could do like this ([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/okzczhuz/5/)):

```
var myModel = {
    simpleProp: "test",
    complexProp: {
        simpleProp2: "test2",
        simpleProp3: "test3"
    },
    toJSON: function () {
        return {
            simpleProp: this.simpleProp,
            complexProp: this.complexProp.simpleProp2
        };
    }
};
```

Just make the toJSON method format the object the way you want it to look and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes everything easier. I'm sure I missed that point in the docs.

Comment: This blew my mind. Been using ko extensively for years and never even thought to do this. Great question, better answer.